Necessary conditions for the intersection of three hyperspheres
Suppose three hyperspheres with centers $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The radii of the spheres are $r_1$, $r_2$ and $r_3$. Let us define $S$ the intersection set of the three hyperspheres.
Necessary conditions for $S$ non-empty are:
$\|p_1 - p_2\| \leq r_1+r_2$, $\|p_1-p_3\| \leq r_1+r_3$ and $\|p_2-p_3\| \leq r_2+r_3$, which are computed pairwise for the three hyperspheres.
I wonder if other necessary conditions exist, which could be even extended as necessary conditions for non-empty $S$ in the case of more than 3 hyperspheres.

This is a very special case of classical theorems due to Menger and Schoenberg (who dealt with the case of arbitrary finite sets of spheres and found necessary and sufficient conditions).

Could you refer me to that literature? Did they work in general Euclidean space?

See my answer here.

Specifically for the case of three hyperspheres, are there simple inequalities?

You are effectively asking the following question:

Consider a metric space $(X,d)$ where $X=\{A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3\}$ is a four-point set. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for existence of an isometric embedding of $(X,d)$ in the 3-dimensional Euclidean space $E^3$?

Here, $A_1, A_2, A_3$ correspond to the centers $p_1, p_2, p_3$ of the spheres in your question and $A_0$ corresponds to a triple intersection point of these spheres. Let $d_{ij}=d(A_i, A_j)$, $0\le i, j\le 3$. In your question, $r_1=d_{01}, r_2=d_{02}, r_3=d_{03}$ are the radii of the spheres with centers $A_1, A_2, A_3$. Of course, $d_{ii}=0$ for all $i=0,...,3$ and $d_{ij}=d_{ji}$. Also, we have to have the triangle inequalities
$$
d_{ik}\le d_{ij} + d_{jk}
$$
for all $0\le i, j, k\le 3$. (You already wrote these in your question.) The last necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of an isometric embedding comes from the Cayley-Menger determinant
$$
D=\left| \begin{array}{ccccc}
d^2_{00} & d^2_{01} & d^2_{02} & d^2_{03} & 1\\
 d^2_{10} & d^2_{11} & d^2_{12} & d^2_{13} & 1\\
  d^2_{20} & d^2_{21} & d^2_{22} & d^2_{23} & 1\\
    d^2_{30} & d^2_{31} & d^2_{32} & d^2_{33} & 1\\
      1 & 1 & 1& 1 & 0\end{array}
    \right|=\left| \begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & r^2_1 & r^2_2 & r^2_3 & 1\\
 r^2_{1} & 0 & d^2_{12} & d^2_{13} & 1\\
  r^2_{2} & d^2_{21} & 0 & d^2_{23} & 1\\
    r^2_{3} & d^2_{31} & d^2_{32} & 0 & 1\\
      1 & 1 & 1& 1 & 0\end{array}
    \right|.
$$
Namely, $D\ge 0$.
For details, see my answer here.
